# Merge tables with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, postgresql-9.4

The title of this question is not accurate but I didn't know how to summarize it. Please feel free to write it again if you can!

Here is an extract of two tables:

Table `table_a`

```
code  | year   | nb_a
------+--------+------
  A1  |   2017 |    1      
  A2  |   2012 |    2
  A3  |   2014 |    2
```

Table `table_b`

```
code  | year   | nb_b
------+--------+------
  A1  |   2013 |    1
  A1  |   2014 |    1
  A2  |   2012 |    1
```

I need to merge these tables in order to get this output:

```
code  | year   | nb_a | nb_b | total
------+--------+------+------+-------
  A1  |   2013 |    0 |    1 |     1
  A1  |   2014 |    0 |    1 |     1
  A1  |   2017 |    1 |    0 |     1
  A2  |   2012 |    2 |    1 |     3
  A3  |   2014 |    2 |    0 |     2
```

I can't find the correct query. I would need something like below (I know it doesn't do the job) but how to get all codes and years merged in one table as codes and years are not all repeated in both tables...

```
SELECT 
  code,
  "year",
  table_a.nb_a,
  table_b.nb_b,
  table_a.nb_a + table_b.nb_b AS total

FROM table_a, table_b
WHERE table_a.code = table_b.code;
```

---

Here are the SQL scripts to create the above tables rapidly:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table_a (code TEXT, "year" INTEGER, nb_a INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE public.table_b (code TEXT, "year" INTEGER, nb_b INTEGER);

INSERT INTO public.table_a (code, "year", nb_a) VALUES (A1, 2017, 1), (A2, 2012, 2), (A3, 2014, 2);
INSERT INTO public.table_b (code, "year", nb_b) VALUES (A1, 2013, 1), (A1, 2014, 1), (A2, 2012, 1);
```

Comment: why 2012 has one row and 2012,2013,2017 - three?..

Comment: Not sure to understand your question... Codes are geographic areas codes, not IDs.

Comment: did I guess?.. you want a full outer join?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yu probably are [looking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) for `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT
  coalesce(a.code,b.code),
  coalesce(a."year",b.year),
  coalesce(a.nb_a,0),
  coalesce(b.nb_b,0),
  coalesce(a.nb_a,0) + coalesce(b.nb_b,0) AS total
FROM table_a a full outer join table_b b on a.code = b.code and a.year = b.year;
 coalesce | coalesce | coalesce | coalesce | total
----------+----------+----------+----------+-------
        1 |     2013 |        0 |        1 |     1
        1 |     2014 |        0 |        1 |     1
        1 |     2017 |        1 |        0 |     1
        2 |     2012 |        2 |        1 |     3
        3 |     2014 |        2 |        0 |     2
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's nearly that! I need the `total` column to be filled and also zero values instead of NULLs.

Comment: What about zero values?

Comment: Still have a problem when your solution is applied to a 4 tables join. See new post opened here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44564673/2508539. Thanks again for help!

Comment: @wiltomap answered that one as well - either use parenthesis or strict order or right ON to get wanted result