# FULL OUTER JOIN to merge tables with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, outer-join, postgresql-9.4

Following [this post,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44562726/2508539) I still have an issue when I apply the answer given by [@Vao Tsun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5315974/vao-tsun) to a bigger dataset made this time of 4 tables instead of 2 tables in the related post mentionned above.

Here are my datasets:

```
-- Table 'brcht' (empty)

insee  | annee  | nb
-------+--------+-----


-- Table 'cana'

insee  | annee  | nb
-------+--------+-----
036223 |   2017 |   1
086001 |   2016 |   2


-- Table 'font' (empty)

insee  | annee  | nb
-------+--------+-----


-- Table 'nr'

insee  | annee  | nb
-------+--------+-----
036223 |   2013 |   1
036223 |   2014 |   1
086001 |   2013 |   1
086001 |   2014 |   2
086001 |   2015 |   4
086001 |   2016 |   2
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
 COALESCE(brcht.insee, cana.insee, font.insee, nr.insee) AS insee,
 COALESCE(brcht.annee, cana.annee, font.annee, nr.annee) AS annee,
 COALESCE(brcht.nb,0) AS brcht,  
 COALESCE(cana.nb,0) AS cana,
 COALESCE(font.nb,0) AS font,
 COALESCE(nr.nb,0) AS nr,
 COALESCE(brcht.nb,0) + COALESCE(cana.nb,0) + COALESCE(font.nb,0) + COALESCE(nr.nb,0) AS total

FROM public.brcht
  FULL OUTER JOIN public.cana ON brcht.insee = cana.insee AND brcht.annee = cana.annee
  FULL OUTER JOIN public.font ON cana.insee = font.insee AND cana.annee = font.annee
  FULL OUTER JOIN public.nr   ON font.insee = nr.insee AND font.annee = nr.annee

ORDER BY COALESCE(brcht.insee, cana.insee, font.insee, nr.insee), COALESCE(brcht.annee, cana.annee, font.annee, nr.annee);
```

In the result, I still have two rows instead of one for `insee='086001'` (see below). I need to get one row per `insee` and in this example, the two `2` values should be on the same line with a `total` column showing a `4` value.

[image]

Thanks again for help!

---

Here are the SQL scripts to create easily the above tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.brcht (insee CHARACTER VARYING(10), annee INTEGER, nb INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE public.cana (insee CHARACTER VARYING(10), annee INTEGER, nb INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE public.font (insee CHARACTER VARYING(10), annee INTEGER, nb INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE public.nr (insee CHARACTER VARYING(10), annee INTEGER, nb INTEGER);

INSERT INTO public.cana (insee, annee, nb) VALUES ('036223', 2017, 1), ('086001', 2016, 2);
INSERT INTO public.nr(insee, annee, nb) VALUES ('036223', 2013, 1), ('036223', 2014, 1), ('086001', 2013, 1), ('086001', 2014, 2), ('086001', 2015, 4), ('086001', 2016, 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by other answers, but perhaps better organized:

```
SELECT *, 
       brcht + cana + font + nr AS total 
FROM   (SELECT insee, 
               annee, 
               SUM(Coalesce(brcht.nb, 0)) brcht, 
               SUM(Coalesce(cana.nb, 0))  cana, 
               SUM(Coalesce(font.nb, 0))  font, 
               SUM(Coalesce(nr.nb, 0))    nr 
        FROM   brcht 
               full outer join cana USING (insee, annee) 
               full outer join font USING (insee, annee) 
               full outer join nr USING (insee, annee) 
        GROUP  BY insee, 
                  annee) t 
ORDER  BY insee, 
          annee;
```

Giving:

```
 insee  | annee | brcht | cana | font | nr | total 
--------+-------+-------+------+------+----+-------
 036223 |  2013 |     0 |    0 |    0 |  1 |     1
 036223 |  2014 |     0 |    0 |    0 |  1 |     1
 036223 |  2017 |     0 |    1 |    0 |  0 |     1
 086001 |  2013 |     0 |    0 |    0 |  1 |     1
 086001 |  2014 |     0 |    0 |    0 |  2 |     2
 086001 |  2015 |     0 |    0 |    0 |  4 |     4
 086001 |  2016 |     0 |    2 |    0 |  2 |     4
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Very clear, thanks! Didn't know about `USING` statement for joins.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
t=# SELECT
 COALESCE(brcht.insee, cana.insee, font.insee, nr.insee) AS insee,
 COALESCE(brcht.annee, cana.annee, font.annee, nr.annee) AS annee,
 COALESCE(brcht.nb,0) AS brcht,
 COALESCE(cana.nb,0) AS cana,
 COALESCE(font.nb,0) AS font,
 COALESCE(nr.nb,0) AS nr,
 COALESCE(brcht.nb,0) + COALESCE(cana.nb,0) + COALESCE(font.nb,0) + COALESCE(nr.nb,0) AS total
FROM public.brcht
  FULL OUTER JOIN public.cana ON brcht.insee = cana.insee AND brcht.annee = cana.annee
  FULL OUTER JOIN public.font ON cana.insee = font.insee AND cana.annee = font.annee
  FULL OUTER JOIN public.nr   ON cana.insee = nr.insee AND cana.annee = nr.annee
ORDER BY COALESCE(brcht.insee, cana.insee, font.insee, nr.insee), COALESCE(brcht.annee, cana.annee, font.annee, nr.annee);
 insee  | annee | brcht | cana | font | nr | total
--------+-------+-------+------+------+----+-------
 036223 |  2013 |     0 |    0 |    0 |  1 |     1
 036223 |  2014 |     0 |    0 |    0 |  1 |     1
 036223 |  2017 |     0 |    1 |    0 |  0 |     1
 086001 |  2013 |     0 |    0 |    0 |  1 |     1
 086001 |  2014 |     0 |    0 |    0 |  2 |     2
 086001 |  2015 |     0 |    0 |    0 |  4 |     4
 086001 |  2016 |     0 |    2 |    0 |  2 |     4
(7 rows)
```

In your example you join `nr` against `font`, while you probably want to join it against `cana`?..

Also please check out here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN

> In the absence of parentheses, JOIN clauses nest left-to-right

**update**

Explaining logic:
try `select * from public.brcht`, adding other table one, by one
column from "righter" tables appear, so when you run all four joined, you get:

```
t=# select * 
FROM public.brcht 
FULL OUTER JOIN public.cana ON brcht.insee = cana.insee AND brcht.annee = cana.annee
FULL OUTER JOIN public.font ON cana.insee = font.insee AND cana.annee = font.annee
FULL OUTER JOIN public.nr   ON font.insee = nr.insee AND font.annee = nr.annee
t-# ;
 insee | annee | nb | insee  | annee | nb | insee | annee | nb | insee  | annee | nb
-------+-------+----+--------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+--------+-------+----
       |       |    | 036223 |  2017 |  1 |       |       |    |        |       |
       |       |    | 086001 |  2016 |  2 |       |       |    |        |       |
       |       |    |        |       |    |       |       |    | 036223 |  2013 |  1
       |       |    |        |       |    |       |       |    | 036223 |  2014 |  1
       |       |    |        |       |    |       |       |    | 086001 |  2013 |  1
       |       |    |        |       |    |       |       |    | 086001 |  2014 |  2
       |       |    |        |       |    |       |       |    | 086001 |  2015 |  4
       |       |    |        |       |    |       |       |    | 086001 |  2016 |  2
(8 rows)
```

so the 8th column is `font.annee` (mind - it is null everywhere) - you join it with `nr.insee` - no matches - so full join takes ALL rows from previous three tables joined and ALL rows from `nr` table - and you get 8 rows

Comment: Why would you join `nr` against `cana`? I don't understand the way to join the 4 tables... In my example, I first joined `brcht` against `cana`, then `cana` against `font`, then `font` against `nr`. It seemed logical to me to proceed like this. Is there a logical way of joining the tables together?

Comment: @wiltomap tried to explain. mind that if you dont use `()` joins happen left to right, so last join joins whole previous set on NULL column - and you get all from (brcht,cana,font) AND all from nr (all - because they have no common values on columns you use to join). Hopefully it makes sense - explaining is not my best skill

Comment: OK I did understand, thank you! The thing is that the content of the 4 tables is going to change periodically so I can't keep adapting the joins depending on this... I need a way to join the tables together that will fit any tables contents.

Comment: then use parenthesis to nest join so each next join would be on "coalesced" value

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform an GROUP BY and SUM() the bigint columns, over the query you are now using.

```
select
    insee, annee
    , sum(brcht) brcht
    , sum(cana) cana
    , sum(font) font
    , sum(nr) nr
    , sum(total) total
from (
    SELECT
     COALESCE(brcht.insee, cana.insee, font.insee, nr.insee) AS insee,
     COALESCE(brcht.annee, cana.annee, font.annee, nr.annee) AS annee,
     COALESCE(brcht.nb,0) AS brcht,  
     COALESCE(cana.nb,0) AS cana,
     COALESCE(font.nb,0) AS font,
     COALESCE(nr.nb,0) AS nr,
     COALESCE(brcht.nb,0) + COALESCE(cana.nb,0) + COALESCE(font.nb,0) + COALESCE(nr.nb,0) AS total

    FROM public.brcht
      FULL OUTER JOIN public.cana ON brcht.insee = cana.insee AND brcht.annee = cana.annee
      FULL OUTER JOIN public.font ON cana.insee = font.insee AND cana.annee = font.annee
      FULL OUTER JOIN public.nr   ON font.insee = nr.insee AND font.annee = nr.annee
      ) d
group by
    insee, annee
```